# How to select only particular values from bunch of JSON response?

Tags: android, json

I want to get only some selected values from the JSON response.For example if JSON contains 100 string values then i need to take the values which are starting with @ symbol from that 100 values.

How can I do that ?

Following is my JSON,

```
[{"Obj" :    
    { "ID":"11",
      "NAME":"XYZ",
      "GENDER":"M" 
    }
    { "ID":"11",
      "NAME":"@XYZ",
      "GENDER":"M" 
    }
    { "ID":"11",
      "NAME":"@XYZ",
      "GENDER":"M" 
    }
```

}]

Here I need to fetch Name which having @ symbol

Comment: first you need to parse the json. Where is the pasring part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below method to get the Name which start with @ :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);// u can change it as per your need
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Obj");// if your `Obj` is an JsonArray
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
  String json_name = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("NAME");
  if(json_name.startsWith("@"))
  {
    Log.d(TAG,"It start with @");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,it looks like working,let me try it

Comment: @Eyes : try geet's answer its really working..!!  +1

Comment: @geet I think `obj` is an object.

Comment: @Ketan yes i thought too. but its bit unclear for me of jsonResponse in question.

Comment: @Eyes you can also use `if(json_name.contains("@"))` if you want to get string having @ at any index.

Comment: @ketan In some cases name itself contains `@` in middle or somewhere in string. so, can not use `if(json_name.contains("@"))`.

Comment: @Eyes Check out my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
 private void parseJSON(String json) {
    try {

        JSONArray items = new JSONArray(<your Json Response>);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
            System.err.println("Object---" + item.getString("Obj"));
            JSONObject obj=item.getJSONObject("Obj");
            for (int j = 0; j < obj.length(); j++) {
                String Name=obj.getString("NAME");
                 if(obj.getString("NAME").toString().contains("@"))
                  {
                    Log.d("Name starts with-->", Name);
                 }
                else
                 {  
                      Log.d("Name does not start with-->", Name);
                 }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

first of all that's not a valid json may be below json is correct format

```
[
    {
        "Obj": [
            {
                "ID": "11",
                "NAME": "XYZ",
                "GENDER": "M"
            },
            {
                "ID": "11",
                "NAME": "@XYZ",
                "GENDER": "M"
            },
            {
                "ID": "11",
                "NAME": "@XYZ",
                "GENDER": "M"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

if your response like above try below code this may help you.

```
      try {
            JSONArray jsoArray = new JSONArray(json);


            JSONArray JobjArray = jsoArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Obj");
                for(int i=0; i < JobjArray.length(); i++)
                {                   
                    JSONObject Jobj = JobjArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Iterator<String> iter = Jobj.keys();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iter.next();
                        Log.v("key--", key);
                        try {
                            Object value = Jobj.get(key);
                            Log.v("value--", ""+value);
                            String str_value = value.toString().trim();
                            if(str_value.startsWith("@"))
                            {
                                Log.d(""+str_value,"value started with @");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // Something went wrong!
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```